# Why can't libclang find a function argument declaration?

Tags: python, parsing, clang, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm writing a tool to find the dependencies of a C function. For example in the tcpdump project there is a function in print-ppp.c

`static void ppp_hdlc(netdissect_options *ndo, const u_char *p, int length)`

netdissect_options is defined in the netdissect.h header.

I'm trying to use libclang to find the code in the header.
However it's not finding it.

Here is the code that I'm using. `definition.spelling`, `definition.location.file`, `definition.location.line` are all missing.

```
import sys
import clang
from clang.cindex import CursorKind
import json
import os

def load_compile_commands(compile_commands_file):
    with open(compile_commands_file, "r") as f:
        compile_commands = json.load(f)
    return compile_commands


def get_translation_unit(compile_commands, source_file):
    if clang.cindex.Config.library_path is None:
        clang.cindex.Config.set_library_file("/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/lib/libclang.dylib")

    index = clang.cindex.Index.create()
    for command in compile_commands:
        if command["file"] == source_file:
            args = command["arguments"][1:-2]
            args.append("-I" + os.path.dirname(source_file))
            args.append("-I/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/lib/clang/16/include/")
            
            return index.parse(source_file, args)
    raise Exception(f"No translation unit found for source file {source_file}")


def function_node(cursor, function_name):

    for child in cursor.get_children():
        if (
            child.kind == clang.cindex.CursorKind.FUNCTION_DECL
            and child.spelling == function_name
        ):
            return child
        
    return None

def get_function_arguments(cursor):
    if cursor.kind != clang.cindex.CursorKind.FUNCTION_DECL:
        raise ValueError("Cursor must point to a function declaration")

    arguments = []
    for child in cursor.get_children():
        if child.kind == clang.cindex.CursorKind.PARM_DECL:
            arguments.append(child)

    return arguments


def find_arg_declatation(project_root:str, file_name: str, function:str):
    

    compile_commands_file = project_root + "/compile_commands.json"
    source_file = project_root +"/"+ file_name

    compile_commands = load_compile_commands(compile_commands_file)
    tu = get_translation_unit(compile_commands, source_file)

    for diagnostic in tu.diagnostics:
        print(diagnostic)
        
    function = function_node(tu.cursor, function_name)
    declarations = []
    types = []
    if function is not None:
        arguments = get_function_arguments(function)
        print(f"Nodes dependent on function '{function_name}':")
        for argument in arguments:
            definition = argument.type.get_declaration()
            print(definition.spelling, definition.location.file, definition.location.line)
            
            
if __name__ == "main":
    find_arg_declatation(<args go here>)
```

Comment: Hi @Brian how to call `find_arg_declaration` properly, what are the arguments?
Would be also good to mention dependencies - tcpdump+llvm at least, and that the operation system is MacOS.

Comment: Not to mention other issues - like undefined references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with abstract syntax trees, it is important to **use the appropriate code standard** (which language/dialect should clang expect?) as well as to **make the code minimalistic** (to avoid pre-mature factoring which leads to mistakes) and to this end I personally recommend a bit of functional programming style. When extracting details from types, **pay attention to composite and dynamic declarations** that may not have an obvious origin definition place. Below I share a much simpler version that does the job.

```
from clang.cindex import Index,Config,CursorKind,TypeKind

# check where is LLVM installed on your machine 
Config.set_library_path('/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/16.0.3/lib')

SCRIPT_PATH = './tcpdump/print-ppp.c'

# C99 is a proper compiler for tcpdump, as per docs
index = Index.create()
translation_unit = index.parse(SCRIPT_PATH, args=['-std=c99'])

# filter to nodes in the root script (ignore imported!)
script_node = translation_unit.cursor
all_nodes = script_node.get_children()
all_nodes = filter(lambda c: c.location.file.name==SCRIPT_PATH, all_nodes)

# filter to function nodes
func_nodes = filter(lambda c:c.kind==CursorKind.FUNCTION_DECL, all_nodes)

# print attributes and their types for each function
for fn in func_nodes:
    print(fn.spelling)
    for arg in fn.get_arguments():
        t = arg.type
        # handle pointers by describing their pointees
        if t.kind == TypeKind.POINTER:
            declr = t.get_pointee().get_declaration()
        else:
            declr = t.get_declaration()
        print('\t', 
            t.get_canonical().spelling,
            t.kind,
            f'arg declared in {arg.location.file}:L{arg.extent.start.line},C{arg.extent.start.column}-L{arg.extent.end.line},C{arg.extent.end.column}',
            f'{declr.spelling} declared in {declr.location.file}:L{declr.location.line}'
        )
```

The output looks like:

```
print_lcp_config_options
     struct netdissect_options * TypeKind.POINTER arg declared in ./tcpdump/print-ppp.c:L403,C39-L403,C59 netdissect_options declared in ./tcpdump/netdissect.h:L161
     const unsigned char TypeKind.ELABORATED arg declared in ./tcpdump/print-ppp.c:L403,C61-L403,C73 u_char declared in /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types/_u_char.h:L30
     const unsigned int TypeKind.ELABORATED arg declared in ./tcpdump/print-ppp.c:L403,C75-L403,C86 u_int declared in /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types/_u_int.h:L30
ppp_hdlc
     struct netdissect_options * TypeKind.POINTER arg declared in ./tcpdump/print-ppp.c:L1359,C10-L1359,C33 netdissect_options declared in ./tcpdump/netdissect.h:L161
     const unsigned char * TypeKind.POINTER arg declared in ./tcpdump/print-ppp.c:L1360,C10-L1360,C25 u_char declared in /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types/_u_char.h:L30
     unsigned int TypeKind.ELABORATED arg declared in ./tcpdump/print-ppp.c:L1360,C27-L1360,C39 u_int declared in /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types/_u_int.h:L30
...
```

which confirms that all arguments and their types have been correctly located.

Last but not least - it is nice to visualize our abstract syntax tree. The following snippet

```
from graphviz import Digraph

dot = Digraph(strict=True)
dot.attr(rankdir="LR", size="20,100", fontsize="6")

node_args = {"fontsize": "8pt", "edgefontsize": "6pt"}

for fn in func_nodes:
    fn_node_name = f"{fn.spelling}\nL{fn.location.line}"
    dot.node(fn_node_name, **node_args)
    for i, arg in enumerate(fn.get_arguments(), start=1):
        arg_node_name = arg.type.get_canonical().spelling
        dot.node(arg_node_name, **node_args)
        dot.edge(fn_node_name, arg_node_name)
        t = arg.type
        # handle pointers by describing their pointees
        if t.kind == TypeKind.POINTER:
            declr = t.get_pointee().get_declaration()
        else:
            declr = t.get_declaration()
        declr_file = f"{declr.location.file}"
        dot.node(declr_file, **node_args)
        dot.edge(
            arg_node_name, declr_file, label=f"L{declr.location.line}", fontsize="6pt"
        )

dot
```

produces this elegant diagram and shows that functions use just few pre-declared types.
[image]

To facilitate working with this code, I also [shared the snippet along with the output on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/maciejskorski/22bed219e4d1c5e619dd5881997d5d79) and a fully working [Colab Notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/maciejskorski/65e877d738d1e9d6adcda631973aa7e5/abstractsyntaxtree_demo.ipynb).

Comment: Thanks Maciej! This is an excellent answer. I think that my code failed because my type comparison was done incorrectly. I changed child.kind == clang.cindex.CursorKind.FUNCTION_DECL to child.kind == CursorKind.FUNCTION_DECL and it worked. Either way your code works great and gets me what I needed.

Comment: That must have been something more, as it is true that CursorKind.FUNCTION_DECL == clang.cindex.CursorKind.FUNCTION_DECL. Anyway I am glad that you find the answer clear, in case of further problems my advice is to work with a more distilled code (e.g. debug just functions extraction).